# Downloaded font not displaying in html file

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded a font, the location of the file is correct but i dont know why it's not working:

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family:"myfont";
  src: url('fonts/Helvetica85Heavy_22449.ttf');
}
h1 { font-family: "myfont" !important }
</style>

<h1> Some text </h1>
```

Somehow the font is not being displayed. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Check your network tab in the chrome devtools, make sure you're not getting a 404 error

Comment: Oh yes, i'm getting a 404 error, what does this mean? I have the ttf file placed correctly

Comment: That means the font path is incorrect , it should be relative to the file that it's being used in

Comment: this font path is not found. check your path is real path exist or not

Comment: I put it in my static folder and now works, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a web font kit to convert it. Try uploading it here first then replacing it in your font directory.

https://www.web-font-generator.com/